# Angular bootstrap ngbdatepicker removing (change) method so Is there any other option to read model value on controller

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, ngb-datepicker

I am trying with bootstrap ngbdatepicker I added datepicker selector to appcomponent.html and datepicker started showing there Now I need to read that model value into controller so I can pass it to parent appcomponent for that I added (change) method  on datepicker but it is removing that method from input so how can I read and pass that value to parent. 
Is there any other option to read that value in controller and pass to parent

Thanks in advance

Below is the template in which I am using the child selector to open datepicker here I added change method but its not triggering on date selection so I am not able to emit the event

Parent Component:

```
<ng-template #modalContent let-close="close" *ngIf="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Add new event</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <label>Start Date</label><date-pick (change)="updateFromChild($event)"></date-pick>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="close()">OK</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

```js
Child Component:

import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'date-pick',
  templateUrl: './datepicker-popup.html'
})
export class NgbdDatepickerPopup {
  model;
  constructor(){  }
  @Output() change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  onChange() {
      console.log('call');
      this.change.emit(this.model)
  }
}
```

```html
Child Template:

<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
             name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (change)="onChange()">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
          <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: is that worked for you ? let me know if any help required

Comment: @PranayRana No it did't. Let me share my code

Comment: its worked for me , provided code in my updated answer , have try

Comment: is that worked for you ?

Answer (score 1):

based on your input , i did like this , and its working

installed : `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

**app.component.html**

```
 <app-date-picker (selectDate)="change($event)" ></app-date-picker>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
change(event) {
    alert(event);
    console.log(event);
  }
```

**datepicker.component.html**

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
             name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" (ngModelChange) = "change($event)" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
          <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**datepicker.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-picker',
  templateUrl: './datepicker.component.html',
})
export class DatePickerComponent {
  model;
  @Output() selectDate = new EventEmitter<any>();

  change(event) {
    this.selectDate.emit(event);
  }
}
```

---

instead of `(change)="onChange()"` make use of `ngOnModleChange`, so it should be `(ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"`

```
 onChange(event) {
      console.log('call');
      this.change.emit(event);
  }
```

---

in angular you can do binding `[(ngModel)]='propety'` to perform two way binding to control.

If you have parent - child component scenario than you need `EventEmitter`, that publish value to your parent component. so you need to have this

```
 //in child component
 @Output() selectDate = new EventEmitter<string>();
 //on change date push date 
 this.selectDate.emit(value);
```

in parent component it should be

```
   <childComponent (selectDate) = 'OnSelectDate($event)'></childComponent>
   //in ts file you need to have method 
   OnSelectDate(event) {}
```

Comment: I added the code please have a look and help if you have any idea

Comment: @DeepakPatidar - make use of `(ngModelChange)="onChange()"` as updated in answer and check its working or not ..

Comment: No luck I think ngbdatepicker removing the ngModelChange as I see the input  field using inspect element  there is no such method 

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: @DeepakPatidar - can you try this `(bsValueChange)="onChange()"`..let me know i used this in my code

Comment: Still not working Please have a look on above attached Image inspect element look like this

Comment: @DeepakPatidar - this one is your control : https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples , right ?

Comment: here I have doubt  why  input  isremoving the method

Comment: @DeepakPatidar - it needs to be worked but i you give me which control library you are using i can try at my end and help you ...

Comment: I am using  angular 5 calendar where for adding new event on particular date  I open a model which have the angualr 5 bootstrap ngbdatepicker  for start date and end date 
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples (Datepicker in a popup)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168802/discussion-between-deepak-patidar-and-pranay-rana).

Answer (score 0):

For reference, if anyone comes here, thinks they have exactly the same code but theirs isn't working, **the order of ngModel and ngModelChange matters!**
NgModelChange has to be somewhere after ngModel or otherwise this won't work correctly. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11234 for details.